# Wanting a Many to Many relationship with single cell

Tags: c#, ms-access-2013

Now i'm sure this is an amateur question and that i'm going about this the wrong way, that's why i'm asking here! So please go easy.

I'm trying to create a database in Access 2013 that will store orders for a POS system (It isn't a commercial product, it's a computing project in C#). It contains several tables.

[image: DB Relationship preview]

My issue is that I can't have multiple `menuitems` for every `orderitem`. Is there a way to do this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think you can maintain another table just for the mapping between `orderitems` and `menuitems`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a MenuOrderItem table that goes between OrderItems and MenuItems.  It will have a 1-to-Many relationship to both OrderItems and MenuItems.  That's how Many-to-Many relationships are built in relational dbs...with an intermediary table.

In your case, to do this, remove the relationship between OrderItems and MenuItems.  Create table called MenuOrderItem (or something similar).  It should have just two columns in it: a column named OrderItemId, and a column named MenuItemId.  These columns will be used to make the two new relationships: the first between MenuOrderItem and OrderItems and the second between MenuOrderItem and MenuItems.

Comment: Thank you, I can't see exactly how it would work though. Please could you give me an example? Sorry, this is totally new to me!

Comment: @StevenChorkley Added more specifics for your particular situation.

Answer (score -1):

One way would be to put a table between orderItems and menuItems with 2 columns.  orderItemID and menuItemID.  Then create your relationships.  This would allow you to have one orderItem with many menuItems.